# ListView with WebView cells not rendering correctly

Tags: listview, webview, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use a `ListView` controls that uses an `ItemTemplate` containing a `WebView`. Page will load a set of chat bubbles ( content of a chat bubble is HTML ).

Now all the code is working fine, but the rendering is a bit off.

Problem 1.
If I don't add `Task.Delay` all cells will be rendered underneath each other. Something to do with the recalculation of the height of the cells.
Any way to get rid of this?

Problem 2.
When all the chat bubbles are loaded and the total content is larger in height than the screen, the `ListView` will still not scroll... Manipulating the `ListView` by using touch, it will often redraw and at that point the scrolling is ok.

All of this feels like I need to wait for all the rendering to be finished and then redraw the page somehow.
Anyone tried doing this?

Here some code of the project, if needed I can post more

ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="ChatListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Chats}"
          HasUnevenRows="true">
    <ListView.Margin>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,30,0,0" />
    </ListView.Margin>      
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <WebView Source="{Binding Content, Converter={StaticResource HTMLConverter}}" HeightRequest="10" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Loading of the data:

```
public void LoadData()
{
    ChatMessage chatUser = new ChatMessage()
    {
        Name = "Glenn Versweyveld",
        Date = DateTime.Now,
        Subject = "Onvoldoende beschikbaar",
        Content = @"<dl><dt>Definition list</dt><dd>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</dd><dt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</dt><dd>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</dd></dl>"
    };

    ChatMessage chatServer = new ChatMessage()
    {
        Name = "HelpDesk",
        Date = DateTime.Now,
        Subject = "Onvoldoende beschikbaar",
        Content = @"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>"
    };

    ChatMessage chatUser2 = new ChatMessage()
    {
        Name = "Glenn Versweyveld",
        Date = DateTime.Now,
        Subject = "Onvoldoende beschikbaar",
        Content = @"<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1><p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href=""#"">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p><h2>Header Level 2</h2><ol><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li><li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li></ol><blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote><h3>Header Level 3</h3><ul><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li><li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li></ul><pre><code>#header h1 a { display: block; width: 300px; height: 80px; }</code></pre>"
    };

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        Chats.Add(chatUser);
        await Task.Delay(50);
        Chats.Add(chatServer);
        await Task.Delay(50);
        Chats.Add(chatUser2);
        await Task.Delay(50);
    });
}
```

Custom iOS WebView renderer:

```
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIWebView uiWebView = ((UIWebView)NativeView);
        Delegate = null;

        uiWebView.DataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorType.None;
        uiWebView.ScalesPageToFit = false;
        uiWebView.ScrollView.ScrollEnabled = false;
        uiWebView.LoadFinished += OnLoadFinished;

        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        var control = ((UIWebView)NativeView);
        control.LoadFinished -= OnLoadFinished;
        Delegate = null;

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void OnLoadFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var control = ((UIWebView)NativeView);

        string contentHeight = control.EvaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('mybody').offsetHeight");
        double height;
        if (double.TryParse(contentHeight, out height))
            height += 8;
        else
            height = 350;

        ((WebView)Element).MinimumHeightRequest = height;
        ((WebView)Element).HeightRequest = height;
    }
}
```